# Problem with using tukey_hsd() inside a function and add_xy_position() in R

Tags: r, function, anova, tukey, rstatix

I have a problem with `add_xy_position()` after using `tukey_hsd()` from the rstatix package inside a function. This is what my function looks like:

```
make_tukey_test <- function (data,variable,grouping_variable){
  data %>% 
    tukey_hsd(variable ~ grouping_variable)
}
```

When I call the function using the following code, it works perfectly fine and the test results are being saved in the data.frame:

```
test <- make_tukey_test(data = dat, variable = dat$num_var, grouping_variable = dat$factor_var)
```

However, when I try to add the x and y coordinates of `dat$factor_var` using `add_xy_position()` like this:

```
test <- test %>%
  add_xy_position(x = “factor_var”)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`. * Column `grouping_variable` is not found.
```

However, when I use `tukey_hsd()` outside of my function, the code works perfectly fine and the coordinates are being added to the data.frame.

I would greatly appreciate some helpful suggestions, as I have no clue why the code doesn't work when I´m using it inside my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to pass column names as strings. Since `tukey_hsd` accepts a formula object you can use `reformulate` to create that and pass the `grouping_variable` as it is in `add_xy_position` function.

Here is an example with `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)

dat <- mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) 

make_tukey_test <- function (data,variable,grouping_variable){
  data %>% 
    tukey_hsd(reformulate(grouping_variable, variable)) %>%
    add_xy_position(x = grouping_variable)
}

test <- make_tukey_test(data = dat, variable = "mpg", grouping_variable = "cyl")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!